# JdbcPagingItemReader vs JpaPagingItemReader which is better to use

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jdbc, spring-batch

I have to write a spring batch job, and need to read 100,000 records daily.

Which implementation of Item Reader is better to use between JdbcPagingItemReader and JpaPagingItemReader.

JpaPagingItemReader will use entity classes and can have out of box Auditor.

Is something similar(Auditor) possible with domain classes used via JdbcPagingItemReader ?

Comment: Only ask one question per question. Voting to close question with answer to first question.